# Bottom bracket creaking

Tags: shimano

I replaced my bottom bracket with a Shimano 113mm cartridge.

Now 3 months later its making a creaking noise; the sound goes when free wheeling though.

Do l need a new cartridge?

Answer (score 2):

Creaking from the BB area can be hard to localize, but there are basically 5 sources:

1. The cups holding the cartridge in place are a hair loose, and the cartridge is moving around a bit.  Not a real big deal but should be fixed.
2. The BB cartridge bearings are going bad somehow.  Unlikely.
3. A pedal is making noise.  Sometimes this is indicative of a bad bearing, sometimes it's just what the pedal does.
4. The pedal is loose where it's screwed into the crank arm.  Needs to be fixed fairly soon, or the crank arm can be damaged.
5. The crank arm is loose on the crank axle.  *This is a serious problem and needs to be fixed right away (if not sooner) to prevent damage to the crank arm and the axle.*

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you replaced your old one, I assume you have to tools to remove it. If that's the case, rather than jump to the conclusion that you need to replace it again, take it off, clean the threads and put some grease there, put it on again. This should help.